# Checking entry in .To Works Sending New Email but Does Not on Reply

Tags: vba, outlook

This code checks for a specific email address on SEND (displays a simple YES/NO message box to send or not).

The code works when sending a NEW email but fails when REPLYing to the coded email address.

When New email - Debug.Print recipient displays the email address.
When Reply email - Debug.Print recipient is null.

If I add a recipient after clicking REPLY, the SEND event works.

Apparently when Outlook populates the TO (and CC) the recipients are not detected (seen as null) on SEND.

As far as I know there is no "Reply" event.

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
' code to verify if email is addressed to a specific email address/recipient

'set appropriate objects

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim sRecip As Outlook.Recipient

Set olApp = Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Msg = Item

'declare variables
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim str3  'this will be set as the specific email address
Dim answer

str1 = Msg.To
str2 = Msg.CC
str3 = "me@anywhere.com"

' test to see if specific email address is in To or Cc
If InStr(1, str1, str3) Or InStr(1, str2, str3) Then
    answer = MsgBox("This email is addressed to = " & str3 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
     "Are you sure you want to send this message?", vbYesNo, "SEND CONFIRMATION")

    If answer = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End If

GoTo ErrorHandle

ErrorHandle:
Set Msg = Nothing
Set objNS = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Found a solution using the Recipients collection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Solution using GetRecipients Collection:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients
Dim str As String
Dim prompt As String

  Set msg = GetMailItem
  Set recips = msg.Recipients

  str = "me@anywhere.com"
  For x = 1 To GetRecipientsCount(recips)
    str1 = recips(x)
    If str1 = str Then
      MsgBox str1, vbOKOnly, str1
      prompt = "Are you sure you want to send to " & str1 & "?"
      If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
      End If
    End If
  Next x
End Sub

Public Function GetRecipientsCount(itm As Variant) As Long
' pass in a qualifying item, or a Recipients Collection
Dim obj As Object
Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients
Dim types() As String

  types = Split("MailItem,AppointmentItem,JournalItem,MeetingItem,TaskItem", ",")

  Select Case True
    ' these items have a Recipients collection
    Case UBound(Filter(types, TypeName(itm))) > -1
      Set obj = itm
      Set recips = obj.Recipients
    Case TypeName(itm) = "Recipients"
      Set recips = itm
  End Select

  GetRecipientsCount = recips.Count
End Function
```

Comment: You're welcome? :) [Working with the Outlook Recipients collection in VBA](http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/working-with-the-outlook-recipients-collection-in-vba/)

Comment: My apologies. I didn't see the connection. (DUH!)  My sincere and honest thanks. An immense help... most appreciated.

Comment: No problem, just don't forget to accept your answer (whenever the system allows you to).